# mmhmm app is blocking my video feed on MacOS. How do I restore my original state back?

Tags: macos, video, html5-canvas

I am actually trying to use getUserMedia HTML5 api to get a video feed. The mmhmm app plugs in between. Uninstalling the app does not help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

another forum I searched also recommended running:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/mmhmmCamera.plugin
```

Which worked for my issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you've already uninstalled mmhmm you'll want to download the uninstall file [here](https://updates.mmhmm.app/mmhmm-uninstall.pkg) and run it. After that, the app and the camera plugin should be gone. Thank you so much for your patience and this will be clearer in the upcoming version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all the files associated to mmhmm that I could find. Finally, deleting the one named mmhmmCamera.plugin worked.